# How to a run command on Linux terminal from a C/C++ program

Tags: c++, c, linux, terminal

I'm using Graphviz to create a graphic of a Data Structure. Graphviz uses the dot language. I already have the Graphviz file which is basically:

```
digraph G {
1->2
2->3
}
```

I need to convert this file into a .ps file:

```
$ dot -Tps graph1.gv -o graph1.ps
```

And what I need to do is to replicate the process through my program. I'm not sure if I'm able to **open up the terminal through my program**, type those instructions in and run them. I'm able to use libraries and open to other ways on how to do this. Let me know if I'm doing this the wrong way or if this can't be done. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: the system() function allows you to run commands...

Comment: `system("dot -Tps graph1.gv -o graph1.ps");`

Comment: Both of your answers solved my question. Thank you very much.